# WCSLEN doesnt work correctly

Tags: visual-c++-2008, tchar

I've got some code

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dwRWBytes;
    TCHAR frmdata1[] = _T("-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"C:\\Windows\\Temp\\hi.exe\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");
    TCHAR frmdata2[] = _T("\r\n-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858--\r\n");
    TCHAR hdrs[] = _T("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d82751e2bc0858"); 

    hFile = CreateFile(L"D://log.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, frmdata1,  wcslen(frmdata1), &dwRWBytes, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    exit(0);
}
```

I can't understand why in log.txt there is only a part of the string `-----------------------------7d82751e2bc0858
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="`

What is the problem? When I've tried to save `frmdata2` the string in log was incomplete too. What should I do? I think there is some problem in `wcslen()` function. Also, I am using VC 2008.

Comment: Please paste code here instead of providing a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `wcslen` tells you how many *characters* something is in length, and `WriteFile` writes *bytes* and `TCHAR` is multi-byte (or two bytes).  So, you've asked `WriteFile` to write half of the characters in the string you've passed to it.

If you want to write all the characters or get the size of the string in *bytes*, you could use `wcslen(frmdata1) * sizeof(TCHAR)`

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that. Thank you very much. So you always have to keep in mind that TCHAR is two-bytes long for all manipulations with this type? I'am little bit confused. How would memcpy operation would look like i will need to put frmdata1 and frmdata2 together?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some detail on calculating bytes--you can use that to calculate what you need for WriteFile or memcpy.  Although, `_tcscpy_s` might be better than memcpy if you're copying strings.